# Is there a metric space with cardinality $> |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

> Definition: A set $X$, whose elements we shall call points, is said to be a
> metric space if with any two points $p$ and $q$ of $X$ there is associated a real
> number $d(p, q)$, called the distance from $p$ to $q$, such that
> $$(a) \ \ \ d(p, q) > 0 \text{ if } p \neq q; d(p, p) = 0;$$
> $$(b) d(p, q) = d(q, p); $$
> $$(c) d(p, q) \le d(p, r) + d(r, q), \text{ for any  } r\in X.$$

since $d(p,q)$ is a real valued function can $|X|>|\mathbb{R}|$ ? If there such $X$ can you give me an example of such a metric space ?

Comment: There are metric spaces of arbitrarily large cardinality. In fact, for any set $X$, you can define a metric on it by $d(p, q) = 1$ whenever $p \neq q$ and $d(p, p) = 0$.

Comment: There are even Hilbert spaces [$\ell^2(I)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#General_%E2%84%93p-space) with arbitrarily large [Hilbert dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension) $|I|$.